# Changing a DIV to "position:fixed" then change it back to "static" and show the rest of DIVs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have several divs, and after some scrolling the second div will be "position:fixed" and again after some more scrolling it will be back to "position:static" but the problem is:

the 4th div will come next NOT the third (because it has passed by scrolling while we are at the 2nd div).

How can I show the third div after the 2nd one?

**Here is the FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/5vzze/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="slide" id="d1">1</div>
    <div class="slide" id="d2">2</div>
    <div class="slide" id="d3">3</div>
    <div class="slide" id="d4">4</div>
    <div class="slide" id="d5">5</div>
    <div class="slide" id="d6">6</div>
    <div class="slide" id="d7">7</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    position: relative;
}

.slide{
    min-height: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var curScrollVal = $(window).scrollTop();

    if( curScrollVal > 500 && curScrollVal < 1500){
        $('#d2').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': 0, 'background-color': 'pink'});
    }
    else if( curScrollVal > 1500 ){
        $('#d2').css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto', 'background-color': 'grey'});

        //How can I show div "#d3" and the rest?
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure if I understand what you mean BUT this is what I think you are asking for.

[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Lighty_46/5vzze/3/) or [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Lighty_46/5vzze/7/)?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var curScrollVal = $(window).scrollTop();

if( curScrollVal > 500 && curScrollVal < 1500){
    $('#d2').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': 0, 'background-color': 'pink'});
    $('#d3').css({'margin-top': '500px'});
}
//now I wanna show the next divs in order
else if( curScrollVal > 1500 ){
    $('#d2').css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto', 'background-color': 'grey'});

    //How can I show div "#d3" and the rest?
}

});
```

Comment: do not double post please

Comment: in that fiddle, why div 1 not showing when i scroll to top?

Comment: @CJRamki There was nothing in there to remove the fixed class when less than 500 ... here is a JSfiddle with that on it too: http://jsfiddle.net/Lighty_46/5vzze/10/

Answer (score 0):

There are 7 divs, each div has 500px in height. Means that 3rd div start at 1001px while your condition is

`"curScrollVal > 500 && curScrollVal < 1500"`

which can be translated into

`"more than 1st div and less than 4th div"`

Meaning, the 2nd div will appear static and pink **after passing 1st div until the beginning of 4th div**

That is the very reason you skipped 3rd div.

Also, you should be using >= rather than > for starting condition, you will skip 1 pixel of the respective div. The effect will only noticeable on window with exactly 500px.

Here is the proper fix [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vzze/9/)