# How do I change the positioning of a button as I scroll to a particular div in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user opens the page, the button is fixed on the bottom of the screen, always visible and it stays there as the user scrolls down the page.

Once it hits a div (footer) the button positioning changes to relative.

Thanks guys!

http://jsfiddle.net/noemitotos/tWpkf/508

```
var targetOffset = $("#footer").offset().top;
var $windowscroll = $(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($windowscroll.scrollTop() >= targetOffset) {
         $('#fixedbutton').css({ "position": "relative" });
     } else {
        $('#fixedbutton').css({ "position": "fixed" });
     }
});
```

Comment: Please post some code so we know what you've tried.

Comment: Although http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064964/changing-a-div-to-positionfixed-then-change-it-back-to-static-and-show-the has a pretty bad solution, it should get you looking in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post some code example so that we can better help you. I'm assuming you are looking for something like - http://jsfiddle.net/tWpkf/498/

In this example the image is fixed-

```
#fixedbutton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px; 
}
```

and the following script simply changes the css on click-

```
$(function() {
  $('.clickme').click(function() {
    $("#fixedbutton").css('position', 'relative');
  });
});
```

UPDATE as per comment- http://jsfiddle.net/tWpkf/511/

Open the console to see how it is getting calculated. I believe the issue is with what `targetOffset` is defined as. As an example, I changed it to  `$("#footer").offset().top - $(window).height() - 100;`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Vinit, just edited your code and added to my original comment to give you an idea of what I'm looking to achieve.

Comment: Works like charm, Vinit! Thank you